# Train Image Classifier (orfea): Could not load selected layer/table

Tags: qgis, orfeo-toolbox, image-classification

When attempting to input vector data into the Orfea TrainImageClassifier, it shows the error: Could not load selected layer/table. Dependent field could not be populated.

This occurs when I attempt to load any vector file.

I have attempted saving the vector file in a shortened file pathway. There are also no gaps or special characters.

Orfea itself has worked with other tools (e.g. segmentation).

I'm unsure what else to try.

GIS version: 3.16.16-Hannover

Orfea version:OTB-8.0.0-Win64

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to work around this problem by using the OTB standalone interface via the Monteverdi app launcher. The vector layer is then loaded and used correctly. Outputs are also then fine.
Unsure why that solves the problem, but presume it is an incompatibility between the QGIS & OTB builds I am using.